# How can I serve up Blazor WASM application... cost effective

Tags: .net, blazor, web-hosting, blazor-webassembly, shared-hosting

I have been searching for solid documentation to serve up my Blazor Wasm application through a linux shared hosting server.

I would really like to get the explanation on how this works... I found many posts/comments on various sites that suggest it can be done... but there are zero specific instructions on how to achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I attempted building the project in release and publishing it... then I proceeded to copy the content of the published directory into the wwwroot folder.

It shows the landing page/view however nothing is functional.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!! I figured it out 3 months later**

for all those who struggle to get there blazor wasm app running in XAMPP or linux server.

Just edit the index.html file, the base tag should not be the root "/" it should be the root of the domain "/Domain/" like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>TestSite</title>
    <base href="/Domain Goes Here!!!!!!!!!!/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="TestSite.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon-192.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have published Blazor WASM app, all you need is in the `wwwroot` folder. These are static files, you don't need any hosting. Free plans, for example from netlify or github are enough.

Check [this repo](https://github.com/tesar-tech/BlazorAndTailwind) to see how the Blazor Wasm app is build and published to github pages using [github action](https://github.com/tesar-tech/BlazorAndTailwind/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-to-gh-pages.yml).

Comment: Yes I see, so I did successfully manage to serve the Blazor Wasm App via Github and Azure Static Web Apps... however, this is not really my need... I want to serve the static files from my linux server... how can I achieve this?